# How do I remove these values in a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
x1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
x2 = [3, 5, 6, 8, 9]
x3 = [2, 4, 5, 7, 13]
x4 = [11, 22, 33, 24, 55, 66]
x5 = [11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

How do I remove the increasing values on every list?

If I removed the increasing in those lists, they should look like this:

```
x1 = [1, 6]
x2 = [3, 9]
x3 = [2, 13]
x4 = [11, 33, 24, 66]
x5 = [11, 7, 1, 6]
```

Comment: What's with the vote down? Is it necessary?

Comment: Skip the first position, check one element and the next. If they are increasing, delete the previous element. repeat

Comment: Say I have a list x = [11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]. In that list the increasing values are from 2 to 5.

Comment: Why not 6 in that list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generator to build up the runs and `yield` the results, e.g.:

```
def runs(iterable):
    iterable = iter(iterable)
    i = [next(iterable)]  # Empty iterable not handled
    for j in iterable:
        while j and i[-1] < j:
            i.append(j)
            j = next(iterable, None)
        i[1:-1] = []      # Removes the middle of the run, if there is one
        yield from i
        i = [j]
    if j:
        yield j

# Using @StephenRauch data set
data = (
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [3, 5, 6, 8, 9],
    [2, 4, 5, 7, 13],
    [11, 22, 33, 24, 55, 66],
    [11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
)

>>> [list(runs(d)) for d in data]
[[1, 6], [3, 9], [2, 13], [11, 33, 24, 66], [11, 7, 1, 6]]
```

Comment: I like...  Upper for you.

Comment: Sweet! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This will remove any increasing elements:

#### Code:

```
def remove_increasing(a_list):
    return [a_list[0]] + \
           [y for x, y in zip(a_list, a_list[1:]) if x >= y] + \
           [a_list[-1]]
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = (
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    [3, 5, 6, 8, 9],
    [2, 4, 5, 7, 13],
    [11, 22, 33, 24, 55, 66],
    [11, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
)

for d in data:
    print(remove_increasing(d))
```

#### Results:

```
[1, 6]
[3, 9]
[2, 13]
[11, 24, 66]
[11, 7, 1, 6]
```

Comment: Change the test in the comprehension

Comment: Why isn't it `[11, 33, 24, 66]`?

Comment: Yeah, just noticed it. It should be [11, 33, 24, 66]. There is something wrong with the code. @Stephen Raunch

Comment: So you both are seeing something I don't.  That was the test case I added because originally there was no decreasing data.  Suggest someone explain why the 33 should be there....

Comment: I took it from the OP's question and examples, he wants the first and last in the increasing run but nothing inbetween, e.g. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] == [1, 6]`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear.  What does "remove the increasing values" mean?

Clearly you don't mean "remove every value that is larger than the previous one", because your example results include the last element which is larger.

But, assuming *you* know what you mean, here's *how* to do it:

To delete a value from a list:

```
mylist.remove(4)
```

To remove the item at a specific position from a list: (remember that Python lists start at position zero, not position one)

```
del mylist[2]
```